# draw simply a rectangle on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I am newbie of C# and WPF.

I want to **draw simply a rectangle on canvas**.

but I could not find the variable which decide **origin point of rectangle**.

```
    void DrawRect(int x, int y) 
    {
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
            Width = width,
            Height = y
            ...???
        };
        mainWindow.canvas.Children.Add(rec);
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The Canvas' [SetTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop.aspx), [SetLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft.aspx), [SetRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setright.aspx), [SetBottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setbottom.aspx) properties should work.

So then

```
mainWindow.canvas.SetLeft(rec, xcoord);
mainWindow.canvas.SetTop(rec, ycoord);
```

Thanks to [JerKimball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48692/jerkimball) for a little more information:

Individual shapes in WPF don't have a "Position", per se - they are positioned by setting the corresponding attached properties on the parent Canvas element

Comment: Brad is correct; Individual shapes in WPF don't have a "Position", per se - they are positioned by setting the corresponding attached properties on the parent Canvas element.